# How can I read an object from a matrix of objects?

Tags: python, oop

I created an object in Python like this:

```
class Cube:
    def __init__(self, extcoeff, scatalbedo, phasefunc):
        self.extcoeff = 1.00
        self.scatalbedo = 1.00
        self.phasefunc = np.matrix([[1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],[0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00],[0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00],[0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00]])
```

Now, I want to create a matrix using this class as elements of said matrix, but in a way that I can easily access specific attributes of each elements. For example, I will need the albedo of the cube which is in the 3,6,9 position of the matrix. Any suggestions on how to do this? Can I call attributes using positions of the matrix? I guess matrix[3][6][9].scatalbedo won't work.

Comment: There are no "attributes" of each element. You mean you just want to take a slice of your matrix?

Comment: yes, something like that. I only need one element at a time